# PHP Authentication Security

Tags: php, authentication

Is secure way to use this script to authenticate user. i'm using this as login.

```
<?php

  $Valid_Passwords = array ("Username" => "Password");
  $Valid_Users = array_keys($Valid_Passwords);

  $User = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
  $Pass = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

  $Validated = (in_array($User, $Valid_Users)) && ($Pass == $Valid_Passwords[$User]);

  if (!$Validated) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Area. Miljan`s Confessions"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die ("You not autorized to access this area!");
  }
?>
```

Comment: That is EXTREMELY insecure. This will tel you exactly how to do a basic but fairly secure one: http://m.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this very simple login example.  You should have a look.  https://github.com/Goddard/simplelogin-example
My example uses ajax/jquery though.

But basically you want to add

```
 filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'username')
 filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'password')
```

This is useful if you are getting a request from a web form, or even command line.  You will need to change INPUT_GET to what input type you are trying to get.